# Range Slider Positioning via CSS

Tags: html, css, input, range

I've been trying to make an Equalizer Interface using HTML and CSS.
Ive tried so many iterations.

I need vertical range sliders with labels on top of each slider, positioned in the centre of their div.

The Range Slider does not seem to fit in its box and its positioning has been a nightmare.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joElL.png)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kTS1.png)

[CSS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7cyW.png)

Comment: Please insert the code into the code snippet for minimal reproducible code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)